# paypal rest api agreement stored credit card

Tags: paypal

I have created a credit card using rest `pay pal` without to mention the payer_id or external_customer_id because I don't need.
He is created and then when I try to pass the id to an agreement I read that to the funding instrument I need to set the credit_card_token in which is stored the credit_card_id returned from `pay pal`.

I did it all, but I can't create the agreement, I would appreciate if someone would know what I missed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PayPal Subscription APIs that include Billing Agreement, would not accept Vaulted Credit Card as a payment source. Please refer to github issue created here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/60

Comment: Thank you !  I will follow that issue.